# Getting error : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'cxf-beans:identifiedType' to a(n) 'type definition' component

Tags: java, spring, websphere, cxf

After submitting request to a web application, while loading a custom jar class bean xml file getting below error( web-sphere server), I have added CXF related jars and name spaces app context file. I have removed all duplicate jars also. Didn't find specific reason why I am getting this error so far

```
10:14:05,290 ERROR [:70065619:0:0:27918150 : null] com.company.bdss.iaa.builder.wfs.ECIRequestBuilder [] - Exception occured during VEAI call eciRequestCall() Line 53 in XML document from class path resource [config/VEAI_RSIAPPCONTEXT.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'cxf-beans:identifiedType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 53 in XML document from class path resource [config/VEAI_RSIAPPCONTEXT.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'cxf-beans:identifiedType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:397)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:539)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.company.bdss.rsi.service.impl.RSIServiceBaseImpl.initBeanFactory(RSIServiceBaseImpl.java:58)
    at com.company.bdss.rsi.service.impl.MultipleCustomerOpenImpl.getMultipleCustomerOpenInstance(MultipleCustomerOpenImpl.java:81)
    at com.company.bdss.iaa.builder.wfs.ECIRequestBuilder.eciRequestCall(ECIRequestBuilder.java:64)
    at com.company.bdss.iaa.builder.wfs.ECIRequestBuilder.getECIRequest(ECIRequestBuilder.java:52)
    at com.company.bdss.iaa.manager.wfs.ECIRequestManager.getECIRequest(ECIRequestManager.java:18)
    at com.company.bdss.iaa.command.wfs.ECIRequestCommand.getECIRequest(ECIRequestCommand.java:16)
    at com.company.bdss.iaa.command.wfs.MessageProcessCommand.generateEICWheneverDontHave(MessageProcessCommand.java:76)
    at com.company.bdss.iaa.command.wfs.MessageProcessCommand.requestInitiate(MessageProcessCommand.java:963)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at com.company.bdss.iaa.asyncwork.wfs.IAAWFRestServiceWork.run(IAAWFRestServiceWork.java:42)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext.run(J2EEContext.java:1178)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.WorkWithExecutionContextImpl.go(WorkWithExecutionContextImpl.java:199)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.CJWorkItemImpl.run(CJWorkItemImpl.java:236)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1783)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'cxf-beans:identifiedType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getGlobalDecl(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.traverseComplexContent(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.traverseComplexTypeDecl(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.traverseLocal(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseNamedElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseGlobal(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.traverseSchemas(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:389)
    ... 30 more
```

Comment: Post only relevant information and your code.

Comment: added pre environment

Answer (score 1):

Your XSD needs to reference (using an import or include) the XSD file which contains this definition . if you are still not able to do post your Spring configuration file